# Brother DCP-L2560DW will it work on ubuntu

Tags: printing

Has anyone used this printer? And do it work properly on Ubuntu 14.04 wireless, the same goes for the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed using this driver: http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=dcpl2560dw_eu&os=128
Printing and scanning seem to work fine.